# Django - Signup redirect to login page not working

Tags: python, django

My Signup view looks like below

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.views import generic
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
  form_class = UserCreationForm
  success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
  template_name = 'signup.html'
```

My urls.py has below redirect rules

```py
from django.urls import path

from .views import SignUpView

urlpatterns = [
  path('signup/', SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
]
```

My signup.html template looks like below

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Sign Up</h2>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
{%  endblock content %}
```

I am trying to redirect to login page once signup completed. But its not working, and one more observation is I see the POST request status as 200, but if I go to login page, I am unable to login with those new credentials.

What error I am doing, any help appreciated.

Thank you.

I am using Django 2.1.5 with Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class SignUpView(CreateView):
```

maybe you imported in wrong way

and you have to override `form_valid()` method

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    valid = super(SignUpView, self).form_valid(form)
    username, password = form.cleaned_data.get('username'), form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    new_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    login(self.request, new_user)
    return valid
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the model in your createview as like:

```
class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
     model = user # your model name here
     form_class = UserCreationForm
     success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
     template_name = 'signup.html'
```